# Rails: How to give user a Notification or custom error page to enable cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user has disabled cookies in his browser and uses my Rails Application, he gets a error: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken because session data can't be stored in a cookie.

I know Rails has the option to disable session data or change the session store, but this is not an option for me. I want to give the user a notification that he should enable cookies when they are disabled in his browser or at least a custom error page. Instead, ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken gives the error message "In your browser are cookies disabled, please enable to make the page work properly".

How can i do that? Can someone provide a snippet of code, since I'm a newbie in Rails, and created my first application with a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, this will show up in the logs (422 error):

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity  
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 9ms
```

A quick and easy way to handle this would be to edit your public/422.html page in the public folder to display your cookie error message. It should be generated by rails by default when you create an app.

If you don't have it, you should be able to just create the file in public/422.html and rails should use it (3.0+ if I'm not mistaken).